# adding Facebook Social Plugins

Tags: facebook-like

I feel completely silly for asking this question, especially after so many years of designing and building web sites. I have been researching for about a week on how to get Facebook Social Plugins working for my site and I am completely stuck. So, I have stripped away everything I can think of and just have a completely basic page here. I have done exactly what the Facebook Developer Tools have said to do and I am getting nothing. Here is my code below, any suggestions would be great!

Just to go ahead and get this out of the way, where it says 'APP_ID', I did put in my app id and I am still not getting anything coming through.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title></title>

<script src="scripts/JavaScript_v1_9_1.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<link href="fonts/OpenSans/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function (d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=APP_ID";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/DippPicks" data-send="true"         data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" data-font="segoe ui"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully used the FB plugins using the code shown [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/#loading), which is:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    // init the FB JS SDK
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID',                        // App ID from the app dashboard
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel file for x-domain comms
      status     : true,                                 // Check Facebook Login status
      xfbml      : true                                  // Look for social plugins on the page
    });

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
  };

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Which slightly differs from the code shown in the FB plugins page when you click the "Get Code" button, by including that `FB.init` block beforehand and passing in the App Id in there instead of in the js.src property.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Ruy. I have tried this already before, but went ahead and tried it again and I am still not receiving anything. I went into the Chrome developer tools and it is saying there was an error when trying to retrieve 'all.js' from Facebook.